# String Replace in Python - Using Re.sub - having additional unnecessary characters

Tags: regex, python-2.7, str-replace

I am using Python 2.7 here where have a String `"portalColumn":"col-0","portlet":` , and I am trying to replace the "col-0" with say "col-1" or "col-2".. So, I am trying to use the Python's `s = re.sub("col-(.*?)", column, portletJsonString)`

It replaces the "col-0" to `"col-10"` when I pass "col-1" in the `column` variable.. and `portletJsonString` is my string in which I want to replace.
So I see this after the re.sub call :
`"portalColumn":"col-10","portlet"`

What is the correct way to replace my string guys? It keeps the 0 intact.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not use `\d+` instead of `.*?`? I mean, you are looking for digits after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out :-)

Just used `.?` instead of `.*?` .. Unnecessary * in there.

Also, as Kenneth mentioned, can use `\d+`